# Outlook 2013 POP 3 Emails are not getting downloaded

Tags: linux, microsoft-outlook-2013, pop3

I am unable to download emails in my outlook.

:: Send and receive occurs smooth
:: I can see the emails on the server
:: Those are not getting downloaded in my Outlook 2013 POP3 setting

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Remake your Outlook Account using Control Panel, Mail(Microsoft Outlook). That is a better way to set up POP3 email. I do this.

Comment: Should it make difference ?

Comment: Did you use GMail?

Answer (score 2):

GMail new authentication scheme only works with outlook 2019 and above.
Work around not found yet.
I have Outlook 2013, it shows gmail login dialog.

Comment: It start to work again. Don't ask me, ask google !

Answer (score 0):

Just follow instructions on a web page: https://www.msoutlook.info/question/902

Step 2: Outlook 2016 (msi) and previous versions; Get an App password for Outlook

I just did it and it worked for me.